# displaying value of dynamic checkbox in next page . and inserting such value

Tags: php

I've created a dynamic checkbox, but failed to display its value on another page. The work I have done is the following:

index.php

```
<form method="post" action="print.php">
    <?php 
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $database="checkbox";

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

    mysql_select_db("$database");
    //Create the query
    $sql = "select test, rate FROM lab";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo <<<EOL
        <input type="checkbox" name="name[]"value="$row['test']}/{$row['rate']}"/>          
        {$row['test']}-{$row['rate']}<br />

        EOL;
    }

    ?>
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

I am trying to display the value on a secon page called print.php:

```
<?php
print $_POST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Silly question... Are you ticking the box before submitting?

Comment: And what did you get?

Comment: yes. but it displays "Array"......

Comment: Checkboxes will not print anything unless you tick the boxes..

Comment: it prints only after checking it...

Comment: and it prints only 'Array'....

Comment: because $_POST['name'] is an array, DUH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See What's happening in your code:-
You are naming your check box in array.
So when you will get the submission in php you will receive an array by the name as :- name[]
So $_POST['name'] will return an array in php.
when you use print method then it can only print variable value .
it can't print array or object . if you use print/echo method to print array/object it will just print their type.
So to print an array you can use **print_r()** method or you can use **var_dump()** to check what is in variable.
you can access array as you favourite way by any loop.
For more about print-r and var_dump please follow manual link
[php.net manual[][1]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: your input is array `name="name[]"` so you can only expect and array at your PHP code. Your array count will be same as the number of items you have checked.

Comment: what should i do to print only value

Comment: foreach ($_POST['name'] as $val){ echo $val ;} it will print only value.

Comment: thanx a lot chandra kishor.... but again i am nowhere..... failed to get sum of the rate printed in print.php

Comment: $rate = 0;
foreach ($_POST['name'] as $val){ 
echo $val ; // it will show value
$valArr = explode("-",$val); // explode will break string from -  and convert it into array
// so $valArr[0] will be test and $valArr[1] will be rate
$rate += $valArr[1];


} 
echo $rate; // will print sum of rate

Comment: `code` $rate = 0; $test = array(); foreach ($_POST['name'] as $val){ echo $val ; // it will show value $valArr = explode("-",$val); // explode will break string from - and convert it into array // so $valArr[0] will be test and $valArr[1] will be rate $rate += $valArr[1]; @user2570995
$test[] = $valArr[0]; // add all test value in array
`code`
 } echo $rate; 
$testStr = implode(",", $test); // now make a string from array bu using your own separator
     // benefit of implode is you will not take care of last comma
echo $testStr;

Comment: the number of test is greater than 70...... so it seems a big page ... how can i display result of array in different column ..... like 20 result per column....

Comment: Dear You are going far away from your question . so put it as closed. and for more help you can turn on chat or can ask other question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `print_r` function to display all values in the array. Like

```
print_r($_POST['name']);
```

Comment: the number of test is greater than 70...... so it seems a big page ... how can i display result of array in different column ..... like 20 result per column....

Comment: You can try something like, http://neoalchemy.org/tablePagination.html . Just follow the second example. Again, it depends on how you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some way for identifying which checkbox is checked. You have couple of options use and index for the variable and get it as index or identify it from the value.

Here i have added $rowNum as index for `name`.

```
$rowNum=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo <<<EOL
  <input type="checkbox" name="name[$rowNum]"value="$row['test']}/{$row['rate']}"/>          
      {$row['test']}-{$row['rate']}<br />

EOL;
$rowNum++;
}
```

Here if you check the first and third checkbox only, at PHP you will get

```
$_POST['name'] = Array
(
    [0] => test0/rate0
    [2] => test2/rate2
)
```

If you are not using the $rowNum as in your code and selecting the same options as above, you will get the folowing output.

```
$_POST['name'] = Array
(
    [0] => test0/rate0
    [1] => test2/rate2
)
```

You can use the array like this at `print.php`

```
if (is_array($_POST['name'])){
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $key=>$name){
        echo $key, '=>', $name,'<br/>';
        //Here $key is the array index and $name is the value of the checkbox
    }
}
```

Comment: yes... the result is exactly same.... but i need to display only value not the array info with value....

Comment: I have added how to use it, if this is what you want.if you are not using the index for names then the `$key` has no meaning as it will be always a continuous number.